# Property file with key containing whitespace

Tags: file, properties, groovy, dictionary

I would like to directly read a property file into a map.
I found an example such as :

```
def propsFile = new File(fileName)
props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
props.each { k,v->
     println "${k} /// ${v}\n"
}
```

Ok, it works correctly for line looking like :

```
toto=titi
```

i.e. where the key contains no whitespace.
But I have to treat a property file where keys will looks like

```
This is a key (example)=Value
```

where `This is a key (example)` will be the key.
And the example above does not work at all as it gives the first word (This) as the key.
So, is there a way to tell that the key value separator is = and no other character.

If not, il will read line by line and split... but i would prefer a more elegant solution if any.

Thanks for your help
J.L.P.

Answer (score 0):

If your properties file is not following the specification (with escaped spaces in the key names) then you'll have to write your own parser I believe, and go line by line.

Not too hard though, you should be able to use something like:

```
String props = '''toto = titi
                 |foo=bar
                 |# comment
                 |
                 |way and hay = yes'''.stripMargin()

Map properties = props.split( '\n' )
                      .findAll { !it.startsWith( '#' ) && it.trim().length() }
                      .collectEntries { line ->
  line.tokenize( '=' )*.trim()
}
```